# android location reminder project

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am a fresher to android application development. Currently, I am working on a project named location reminder. 
How to make mark on the map when the certain location is touched? And also after marking the location, it should be clickable and should direct to other activity.

Answer (score 3):

[Example Which u Want](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/)

**Just Go through Above Link It will help u .....**

Comment: The example you gave above uses a deprecated library.